# Google Apps Script Cannot find method isRequired(boolean)

Tags: google-apps-script

I thought for sure it worked an hour ago, but after making a completely new form and copying the minimal amount of code, the auto-suggested function [isRequired()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/scale-item#isrequired) is still throwing an error...

```
function doGet() {
  var form = FormApp.create("New form");
  var foo = form.addScaleItem();
  foo.isRequired(true);
}
```

`Cannot find method isRequired(boolean). (line 4, file "Code")`

Anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the function you are looking for is

```
foo.setRequired(true)
```

Whereas the isRequired() function is used to figure out if the item is required like so:

```
if(foo.isRequired()) {
Logger.log("Required item")
}
```

Hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

`isRequired` determines whether the item is currently set as required. To set it as required you need to use `setRequired(true)`.